# Doxygen: Group modules and pages?

Tags: documentation, markdown, doxygen

I have a question about pages and groups in doxygen. 
I have a project, where I grouped classes etc. with the *@defgroup* and *@ingroup* cmds. So far this works fine.

Now I'd like to add special documentation to the project with markdown pages. These pages should appear in the dedicated module (group). I tried to create pages with the *@page* and *@subpage* cmds. That works fine, but the pages appear plain in the menu.

So I tried to add them to the groups with *@ingroup*. But that doesn't work as I guessed. 
Is it possible to add pages to modules (groups)?

The result should look like this:

Project
   |-- Modules
   |      |-- "Module1"
   |      |       |-- documentation page1 (from *.md file)
   |      |       |-- class documentation
   |      |-- "Module2"
   |      |       |-- documentation page2
   |      |       |-- class documentation

I hope you can help me!

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Did you have any luck with it?

Comment: I've also got problems with MD pages and groups.  I've found it partly works if there is only one ingroup per MD file.

Answer (score 0):

To group pages you need to use the subpage functionality, no the group.

So create a page for each group that references both subpages and the module group.

```
/*! \page group1page A documentation page for my group
This page contains the info about group 1 \ref group1_label
\subpage group1page2
\subpage group1page3
*/
```

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#subpaging

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsubpage