# Does Doxygen @file work in markdown files?

Tags: documentation, markdown, doxygen

I have a problem with a mix of markdown and `@file` in my `.md` files that I am processing with Doxygen 1.8.5.

If I use:

```
# Release Notes

@file releases.md
Release notes

@tableofcontents

@section rel_page Release History

Blah blah blah
```

I get nothing other than the page title (resulting from the first `#` line) in the HTML. For completeness, this happens with or without the 'releases.md' filename being present (it's optional according to the manual).

However, if I *remove* the `@file` line...

```
# Release Notes

@tableofcontents

@section rel_page Release History

Blah blah blah
```

It all works perfectly.

Have I got the syntax wrong, is @file not supported as part of Doxygen's markdown support, or is this a bug?

There's nothing in the Doxygen manual in either the `@file` or markdown sections about any constraints.

There's some similarity with my other (tumbleweed) [question about markdown and groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704822/how-to-use-markdown-pages-and-doxygen-groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands listed in the section [structural indicators](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) in the manual do not work with markdown. You can get the effect of using `@file` as follows:

```
Release notes {#releases}
=============

@tableofcontents

@section rel_page Release History

Blah blah blah
```

Comment: It would be great to get that information into the manual.  Pity it doesn't work, the mix of markdown and structural doxygen would have been extremely useful - it's why we initially chose doxygen for the task.

Comment: If you could file a bug report for this in the bug tracker (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen) with an example that you would like to see working, then I'll have a look what it takes to support this (or add a remark in the manual if it turns out to be too difficult).