# Do not include custom markdown pages as top-level pages when including them as subpage?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-addtogroup

I include markdown files in my groups in doxygen like so:

```
/**
 * @addtogroup foobar "Foo Bar"
 * @{
 * @subpage doc_foo_bar
 */
```

And they show up in the module documentation as requested. But anyways, they show up as normal top-level-pages, like so:

```
project
 - foo_bar   <-- The "doc_foo_bar" custom markdown page
 - modules
 - - foobar  <-- The module "foobar", which includes a "detailed documentation", which links to the markdown page
```

How to remove the top-level markdown page if it is already included in the module documentation group?

I hope my explanation is plain.

Comment: I don't believe you can.  The grouping commands are for grouping code modules.  @page etc. are for NON-code-module text.  You can't successfully mix them (which is a pity as it seems an obvious missing feature).  I fell foul of this one about a year ago when wanting to use groups and markdown myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704822/how-to-use-markdown-pages-and-doxygen-groups?rq=1