# In Doxygen, how can I generate group documentation with a .md "launch page"?

Tags: doxygen

Somewhat related to [How to use Markdown pages and Doxygen groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704822/how-to-use-markdown-pages-and-doxygen-groups):

I would like to write a high level subsystem description using a .md file using Doxygen's markdown processor. Intuitively, it would seem that this file should have the @defgroup , and that .hpp files would have @ingroup  in key classes, functions, etc.

But this doesn't seem to work well with pure .md files. If I do this at the start of a .md file:

```
# My Subsystem {#Subsystem}
[TOC]
# First Real Header
```

Then I will get a @page Subsystem, but I can't add code constructs to that group (@ingroup Subsystem has no effect).

If I do this at the start of a .md file:

```
@defgroup Subsystem My Subsystem
[TOC]
# First Real Header
```

It kind of works, but no TOC is generated, and the page is laid out like:

```
Files
-----
...
Classes
-------
...
Detailed Description
--------------------

First Real Header
----------------
...
```

Ideally, I would have liked the detailed description before files/classes/functions, etc., but maybe I'm asking for too much. Also, the missing [TOC] seems odd, but maybe I'm misusing the grouping behavior for something it wasn't intended for.

If anyone has done this type of thing successfully (Subsystem .md page + merged sourced content), please let me know.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using ?

Comment: I have tried both 1.8.15 and 1.9.1.